Curious usage of the definite article for a singular noun in a book

The great aliens play this game cautiously. ... The alien decided to
move a flat piece to the right.*

* Some wording is changed, but same as in the original; the noun for the does not appear neither before the quotation nor in ... (BTW the original or a original here?)
I think the in The great aliens means that it is not all aliens, but some particular ones, correct? article usage: "the faces of the human"
But as for the in the alien I'm confused. It does not seem to signal being a representative of a class (Curious use of the definite article with body parts in dictionary definitions), but within ... alien(s) were not mentioned. What could it mean here?

I’m voting to close this question because without the full context (a link to the source of the cited text) we've no way of knowing what the great aliens refers to. There might be two completely different types of aliens (big ones and small ones) from different planets. Or maybe it just means those aliens who are particularly good at playing this (unknown) board game. And only the prior context would tell us who the alien is.

You're confused, and so are we. Yes, "the alien" seems to refer to one specific alien. But with the two sentences posted here, we can't tell you anything more than that. Voting to close as unclear; feel free to edit to give more of the passage.

@FumbleFingers, "aliens" were not mentioned in the text before at all, I'm adding it to the body of the question.

@AndyBonner "aliens" were not mentioned in the text before at all, I'm adding it to the body of the question.

If you've "added text" to some original, it sounds to me like you're asking us to tell you what your own text means - still without context!

@FumbleFingers, while ANY change might (and does) effect outcome, I've tried to change in a way not to effect meaning of the articles.  ... is rather long and the book is copyrighted. Maybe the title better be changed though, but I made it to differ from other QAs here.

Meaning - the great aliens and the alien

The great aliens play this game cautiously. ... The alien decided to move a flat piece to the right.*

There are two definite articles (the)

The Great aliens: "the great" is an adjective used to describe a group (or race) and it indicates this alien race's esteemed status, power, or achievements.(It need not be mentioned everytime we mention the race) It is similar to


Alexander, the Great
The Great Mongols
The Great Ottoman Empire


the alien : This refers to a specific alien (belonging to the great aliens race), who is playing the game. The game referred is an individual game (like chess ♟️ "moved a flat piece")
"play this game cautiously" doesn't mean that the game is a team game. Each member when they individually play the game, they play cautiously.


"the alien : This refers to a specific alien, who is playing the game."  But from 1st sentence multiple aliens play and there was no info to distinguish that one.

@Martian2020 The alien decided to move a flat piece to the right.. It means the game they played was not a team game. but an individual game.

@Martian2020 I edited my answer for explaining what I understood from the text you gave. Perhaps you can get more details from the book and clarify.

Thank you. Having many individual games makes sense. Now I would like some confirmation (e.g. upvotes to your answer) that it is indeed valid meaning (and maybe the only valid?) and that is indeed what most readers might deduce from usage of "the" in this context. P.S. in the original the word chess was indeed used (and I'm not sure about the in here again!).

@Martian2020 If chess (different kind maybe) is the game, then "the" for one player who is playing is correct. Maybe you can find more in the book. If it isn't a popular book, chances are only few people may have read it. (I haven't)

The book uses chess as allegory of something interconnected and essentially singular (our Universe and it is a physics book). Hence I've understood it is one Game. It is only using the with one particular player later that [as you suggest] indicate the Game is split in many (maybe for easier analysis as scientific minds like to do?).


In your question you're correct it's 'the original' not 'a original' because you are being specific on which original. Secondly, if it were 'a original' in which case it is an arbitrary original it would be 'an original' because original begins with a vowel
You are correct in 'The great aliens' doesn't refer to all aliens but a specific group of 'great aliens'
The 'the' in 'the alien' means you are talking about 1 alien in particular


Normally you'd say something like this:

Great players know when to go on the defensive. The greatest players make a defensive move that permits a counterattack.

You don't need the article with "great players".   You do need an article with "the greatest players".
Now, if you're going to continue on with a statement about a particular player, you can use "the" only if you have previously mentioned that particular player.  If you're going to speak of the player for the first time, you could say:

But this player was not a great player.

or

But {player name}  was not a great player.

